# props are visible as attributes in html element using styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Are **height** & **width** keywords for styled-components?

VSpace.tsx

```
type VSpaceProps = { readonly height?: string; };

export const VSpace = styled.div`
  height: ${({ height }: VSpaceProps) => height};
  width: 100%;
`;

VSpace.defaultProps = { height: '.5rem' };
```

index.tsx:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <VSpace height="0.4rem" />
  );
}
```

output:

```html
<div height="0.4rem" class="VSpace-sc-18gziyv-1 kkKpPd"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `height` is visible because its one of JSX attributes, it's not related to styled-components.

```
// height is a JSX.attribute type of div element
function App() {
  return (
    <div height="0.4rem" />
  );
}
```

You can check its TS type:

```
Type '{ height: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.
```

See [JSX in Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).